# using module_invoke_all to submit a form question

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

here is more detailed explanation:
i am using the ubercart module with the file download feature module (the uc_file module ).
i have created a product class (which is a new content-type as far as the drupal system) and add a cck file field to it.
what i want to achive is the following behavior:
once a user saves a new node of my product class, i want the uploaded file to be added as a file download feature to the product class automatically.
i know i can hack the function uc_file_feature_form_submit($form, &$form_state), do what it does in my module code, but i rather ivoke it since i'll have easier life with future changes to the uc_file module (since i am calling it's function, i dont care if it will change in the future).
so, to invoke the uc_file_feature_form_submit function i need to build fake $form, &$form_state parameters, i know i can print_r those arrays, and build it from there, the thing is that there are a lot of data in those arrays that is not mandatory, i was wondering what are those mandatory fields that i have to build on my own.
thank you...

Comment: can you give more background as to what you are trying to do? I think we can help you better if you give some background on what you are trying to do from where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Look at the submit function you are trying to invoke. The form values that it's using are the ones you need.

Long answer . . . need more info before I can give a better answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
i have changed my question to include much more detailed  information. can you please re read it ?

Comment: turns out that the answer is pretty simple for this case. i have looked at the function uc_file_feature_form_submit, saw which parameters it uses, add those params to my fake $form_state arr. and it's working.
thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [drupal_execute()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_execute/6) to programatically execute a form. I am not sure if it works with files though.